# Errors Starting and Stopping Mic via AUGraph

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I'm using AUGraph to access the microphone. Everything seems to work 90% of the time but way too often I'm seeing crash reports either at `AudioOutputUnitStart` or `AudioOutputUnitStop`.

They are accompanied by pretty cryptic error messages

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -66635.)`

and

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)`

respectively.

Are there any ways to reduce the chance of these operations failing or is the guidance to simply catch the exceptions and move on?

**Update w/ Sample**

```
- (void)start
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
        AudioOutputUnitStart(_unit);
    });
}

- (void)stop
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
        AudioOutputUnitStop(_unit);
    });
}

- (void)setup
{  
    AudioComponentDescription inputDescription;
    inputDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    inputDescription.componentSubType = _useVoiceProcessingIO ? kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO : kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    inputDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    inputDescription.componentFlags = 0;
    inputDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(nil, &inputDescription);

    AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &_unit)
    AudioComponentCopyName(inputComponent, (CFStringRef *)&_label)

    int enable = 1;
    AudioUnitSetProperty(_unit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, IO_INPUT_BUS, &enable, sizeof(enable)

    AudioStreamBasicDescription format;
    format.mChannelsPerFrame = self.desiredChannels;
    format.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    format.mBitsPerChannel = SAMPLE_LENGTH * 8;
    format.mBytesPerFrame = (format.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * format.mChannelsPerFrame;
    format.mBytesPerPacket = format.mBytesPerFrame * format.mFramesPerPacket;
    format.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    format.mSampleRate = self.desiredClockRate;
    AudioUnitSetProperty(_unit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, IO_INPUT_BUS, &format, sizeof(format)

    int disable = 0;
    AudioUnitSetProperty(_unit, kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer, kAudioUnitScope_Output, IO_INPUT_BUS, &disable, sizeof(disable)

    AURenderCallbackStruct callback;
    callback.inputProc = CaptureAudioUnitInputCallback;
    callback.inputProcRefCon = self;
    AudioUnitSetProperty(_unit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, IO_INPUT_BUS, &callback, sizeof(callback)
    AudioUnitInitialize(_unit)
}
```

Comment: perhaps post code of your AUGraph Setup/initialization? I've never had this issue.

Comment: Sure, I'll post some edits above.